# Difference between direct cast to interface using map vs type parameter in Angular http get?

Tags: angular

What's the difference between

```
  getAnnotationFormats(): Observable<AnnotationFormat[]>{
    return this.http.get<AnnotationFormat[]>(this.annotationFormatsUrl)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

and

```
  getAnnotationFormats(): Observable<AnnotationFormat[]>{
    return this.http.get<AnnotationFormat[]>(this.annotationFormatsUrl)
    .pipe(
      map(response => response as AnnotationFormat[]),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

In the top example, I know that I am passing the type interface AnnotationFormat[] for the resulting object as a type parameter to the call. So does that happen first, before anything in my pipe?

Also if it does happen first, am I casting whatever is being streamed from the http get to the interface AnnotationFormat[]? What if it doesn't fit the interface AnnotationFormat? Why even type the get call if interfaces don't even exist at compile time?

Also, is there any difference between

```
map( response => response as AnnotationFormat[])
```

and

```
 return this.http.get<AnnotationFormat[]>(this.annotationFormatsUrl)
```

Another example is something like this:

```
  getTasks(): Observable<Task[]>{
    return this.http.get<Task[]>(this.tasksUrl).pipe(
        map(response=> response['results'] as Task[]),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Is the  saying that whatever is returned from the chain should be of type Task[]? Or is whatever is being streamed by the get being typed as Task[] first before going through the pipe? And if what's being streamed in from http.get can't be typed as Task[], is it just being passed through the pipe as an untyped object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of misunderstandings in your question.

```
this.http.get<AnnotationFormat[]>()
```

Specifying the type parameter here (`<AnnotationFormat[]>`) allows the TypeScript **compiler** to select the overload of the `get()` method that returns an `Observable<AnnotationFormat[]>`. It also tells the reader that you expect the response body to be a JSON document of type `AnnotationFormat[]`.

It has absolutely no effect at runtime. Only at compilation time. Without this, the type of the return value would be inferred by the compiler as `Observable<Object>`. Again, this doesn't change anything at runtime.

Next point:

```
map(response => response as AnnotationFormat[])
```

This is completely useless. `response`is **already** of type `AnnotationFormat[]`, since you used `http.get<AnnotationFormat[]>`.

Next point:

```
getTasks(): Observable<Task[]>{
  return this.http.get<Task[]>(this.tasksUrl).pipe(
    map(response=> response['results'] as Task[]),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

This makes no sense at all. Indeed, `this.http.get<Task[]>` means that you expect the response body to be a `Task[]`, i.e. an array of Tasks, serialized as JSON. But `map(response=> response['results'] as Task[])` means that you changed your mind, and that finally, you expect the response body to be an object with a `results` property which is an array of Tasks. It can't be one and the other. So one of these is wrong. If you expect the body itself to be an array of tasks, then the map() should be removed. If you expect the body to be an object with a results field, then the code should be

```
getTasks(): Observable<Task[]>{
  return this.http.get<{ results: Task[]; }>(this.tasksUrl).pipe(
    map(response => response.results),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Finally, I would like to insist once again that all of this metters only for the TypeScript compiler, and for the readers of your code. At runtime, Angular will get JSON, will parse it, and will result whatever is results, without caring whether it matches with your expectations or not.

What you're calling a "cast" is not a cast. It doesn't make any runtime type check as a real cast would do. The correct term is [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), which is just a way for you to tell the TypeScript compiler: trust me, I know what I'm doing, and I know that this value has the given type.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer! Is it still necessary to specify type parameter if my http get is inside of a function with the correct return type (in my example, AnnotationFormat[])?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you'll get an error from the compiler telling you that Observable<Object> is not assignable to Observable<Task[]>